# Custom validation with vee-validate and yup is always triggered

Tags: vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

In a nuxt 3 project, I use the vee-validate and yup to perform custom form validation. Maybe I did something wrong with the usage, the custom validation is always triggered when the value from other field is changed. From the following example, there are two input fields. When the input field "value1" is changed, both custom validations are triggered. Is there any way I can fix it? The custom validation should only be triggered when the relative field is changed.

BaseFormInput.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label class="form-label">{{ label }}</label>
        <input
            v-model="value"
            :disabled="disabled"
        />
        <span>{{ errorMessage }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useField } from 'vee-validate';

const props = defineProps<{
    label: string,
    formControlName: string,
    disabled?: boolean
}>();

const { value, errorMessage } = useField<string>(() => props.formControlName);

</script>
```

Here is the app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <BaseFormInput 
        label="Value1"
        form-control-name="value1"
    />
    <BaseFormInput 
        label="Value2"
        form-control-name="value2"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate';
import { object, string } from 'yup';

useForm({
    initialValues: {
        value1: 'value 1',
        value2: 'value 2'
    },
    validationSchema: object({
        value1: string().required().test('is valid email', 'invalid email', (value: string) => {
          console.log("custom email validation")
          return value.length > 10
        }),
        value2: string().required().test('text', 'invalid text', value => {
          console.log("custom text validation")
          return value.length > 10
        }),
    })
})

</script>
```

"vee-validate": "4.11.3",
"yup": "1.2.0",
"nuxt": "3.6.5"

Comment: I don't think this is possible with form-level validation, it will always validate all fields. You could switch to field-level validation though